# Is there away to have cell value add or delete copies of either cell ranges or worksheets without use of a button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a cell value dictate how many copies should be made. I'm trying to make it if the cell value goes down that it will delete the sheets that are higher than the value. I currently have the adding working no problem just can't figure out how to make it delete copies when the value gets smaller. I figure I could make a button do a check just trying to make it more automated.

```
Sub CreateDistro()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim Name As String
    Dim xActiveSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ActiveSheet = ActiveSheet
    Num = Range("C1")
    If Num > 1 Then
        For i = 1 To Num
            Name = ActiveSheet.Name
            xActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Name)
            ActiveSheet.Name = "Distro-" & i
        Next
    End If
    xActiveSheet.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Look for the worksheet_change event

Answer (score 0):

Problem of the code below: it reacts on the Range("C1") of all sheets!
You might want to use a named range or limit the number of possible sheets
(e.g. minimum number of sheets = 2, template to be copied is sheet 2,
only sheet1 has the `Worksheet_Change` code.

**Sheet1:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Call ChangeSheets(target)
End Sub
```

**Module1:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeSheets(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim iCt As Integer
    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim maxSh As Integer

    'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
    '    MsgBox ("C1: " & Target.Value)
    'End If

    If target.Value <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Minimum worksheet count = 1!" & vbCrLf & "Nothing to do!"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        target.Value = 1
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        maxSh = Sheets.Count
        For iCt = maxSh To 2 Step -1
            Sheets(iCt).Delete
        Next iCt
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Worksheets.Count = target.Value Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet count = " & target.Value & vbCrLf & "Nothing to do!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'add some sheets
    If Worksheets.Count < target.Value Then
        Num = target.Value - Worksheets.Count
        For iCt = 1 To Num
            ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Next iCt
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'delete some sheets
    If Worksheets.Count > target.Value Then
        Num = Worksheets.Count - target.Value
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        maxSh = Sheets.Count
        For iCt = 0 To Num - 1
            Debug.Print maxSh - iCt; ": "; Sheets(maxSh - iCt).Name
            Sheets(maxSh - iCt).Delete
        Next iCt
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```